# Tool to convert WebForm view engine markup to Razor view engine markup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does (or will) a tool exist to convert WebForm view engine markup (aspx) to Razor view engine markup (cshtml)?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

We too faced the problem of converting plenty of WebForms views to Razor. And guess what, we've also came up with a tool:

https://github.com/telerik/razor-converter

It also relies on regexes (and quite a few of them) to make sense of the WebForms mumbo-jumbo, much like the tool by JohnnyO. Ours *might* cover a few more cases, but don't take my word for it and try it on a few views instead.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tool.  One issue I found was that my server comments were removed during the conversion.  It'd be nice to have them converted to the `@* ... *@` syntax.

Comment: How does Telerik's solution compare to this [MVC ASPX to Razor View Converter](http://razorconverter.codeplex.com/) project on Codeplex?

Answer (score 11):

Here's a simple Console App that I wrote to convert WebForms views to Razor. Unfortunately, it's not bullet proof.  I've converted about 20 views with this, and I'm finding that for simple views, it gets it 100% correct, but when the view gets really complicated, the conversion is only about 80% correct.  Even at 80%, it's still better than having to start from the beginning by hand.

There are some things in this conversion tool that may be specific to how I designed my WebForms views, so I commented it so that you can remove it or customize it.

You can use it by executing the console app and passing in a folder path or file path.  If you pass in a folder, it will convert all .aspx and .ascx files in the folder (but it will not recurse down into sub-folders).  If you pass in a file path, it will only convert that file.  Once it's done with the conversion, it will create a new .cshtml file with the same name as the .aspx or .ascx file.

WARNING: If you already have a .cshtml file with the same name as the .aspx/.ascx file that you're trying to convert, this app will overwrite the .cshtml file when it completes the .aspx/.ascx conversion.

USE AT YOUR OWN RISK.  MAKE SURE TO BACK UP EVERYTHING BEFORE USING THIS TOOL.

Note: if your aspx/ascx file is marked as "read only", you will get an error because the console app will not be able to open it. Make sure the read only flag is turned off on all aspx / ascx files that you're trying to convert.

```
class Program {
    private readonly static string razorExtension = ".cshtml";

    /// <summary>Usage: RazorConverter.exe  "C:\Files" or RazorConverter.exe  "C:\Files\MyFile.aspx"</summary>
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        if (args.Length < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("File or folder path is missing.");
        string path = args[0];

        List<string> convertedFiles = new List<string>();
        Regex webFormsExtension = new Regex(".aspx$|.ascx$");
        if (Directory.Exists(path)) {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.aspx")) {
                var outputFile = webFormsExtension.Replace(file, razorExtension);
                ConvertToRazor(file, outputFile);
                convertedFiles.Add(file);
            }

            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.ascx")) {
                var outputFile = webFormsExtension.Replace(file, razorExtension);
                ConvertToRazor(file, outputFile);
                convertedFiles.Add(file);
            }
        } else if (File.Exists(path)) {
            var match = webFormsExtension.Match(path);
            if (match.Success) {
                ConvertToRazor(path, webFormsExtension.Replace(path, razorExtension));
                convertedFiles.Add(path);
            } else {
                throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} file isn't a WebForms view", path));
            }
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("{0} doesn't exist", path));
        }

        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("The following {0} files were converted:", convertedFiles.Count));
        foreach (var file in convertedFiles) {
            Console.WriteLine(file);
            }
    }

    private static void ConvertToRazor(string inputFile, string outputFile) {

        // Known Bug: when writing anything directly to the response (other than for HTML helpers (e.g. Html.RenderPartial or Html.RenderAction)),
        // this Converter will not correctly generate the markup. For example:
        // <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %> will properly convert to @{ Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); }
        // but
        // <% MyCustom("Foo"); %> will incorrectly convert to @MyCustom("Foo");

        string view;
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs)) {
            view = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // Convert Comments
        Regex commentBegin = new Regex("<%--\\s*");
        Regex commentEnd = new Regex("\\s*--%>");
        view = commentBegin.Replace(view, "@*");
        view = commentEnd.Replace(view, "*@");

        // Convert Model
        Regex model = new Regex("(?<=Inherits=\"System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<|Inherits=\"System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<)(.*?)(?=>\")");
        Regex pageDeclaration = new Regex("(<%@ Page|<%@ Control).*?%>");
        Match modelMatch = model.Match(view);
        if (modelMatch.Success) {
            view = pageDeclaration.Replace(view, "@model " + modelMatch.Value);
        } else {
            view = pageDeclaration.Replace(view, String.Empty);
        }

        // TitleContent
        // I'm converting the "TitleContent" ContentPlaceHolder to View.Title because
        // that's what TitleContent was for.  You may want to ommit this.
        Regex titleContent = new Regex("<asp:Content.*?ContentPlaceHolderID=\"TitleContent\"[\\w\\W]*?</asp:Content>");
        Regex title = new Regex("(?<=<%:\\s).*?(?=\\s*%>)");
        var titleContentMatch = titleContent.Match(view);
        if (titleContentMatch.Success) {
            var titleVariable = title.Match(titleContentMatch.Value).Value;
            view = titleContent.Replace(view, "@{" + Environment.NewLine + "    View.Title = " + titleVariable + ";" + Environment.NewLine + "}");
            // find all references to the titleVariable and replace it with View.Title
            Regex titleReferences = new Regex("<%:\\s*" + titleVariable + "\\s*%>");
            view = titleReferences.Replace(view, "@View.Title");
        }

        // MainContent
        // I want the MainContent ContentPlaceholder to be rendered in @RenderBody().
        // If you want another section to be rendered in @RenderBody(), you'll want to modify this
        Regex mainContent = new Regex("<asp:Content.*?ContentPlaceHolderID=\"MainContent\"[\\w\\W]*?</asp:Content>");
        Regex mainContentBegin = new Regex("<asp:Content.*?ContentPlaceHolderID=\"MainContent\".*?\">");
        Regex mainContentEnd = new Regex("</asp:Content>");
        var mainContentMatch = mainContent.Match(view);
        if (mainContentMatch.Success) {
            view = view.Replace(mainContentMatch.Value, mainContentBegin.Replace(mainContentEnd.Replace(mainContentMatch.Value, String.Empty), String.Empty));
        }

        // Match <%= Foo %> (i.e. make sure we're not HTML encoding these)
        Regex replaceWithMvcHtmlString = new Regex("<%=\\s.*?\\s*%>"); // removed * from the first <%=\\s.*?\\s*%> here because I couldn't figure out how to do the equivalent in the positive lookbehind in mvcHtmlStringVariable
        Regex mvcHtmlStringVariable = new Regex("(?<=<%=\\s).*?(?=\\s*%>)");
        // Match <%, <%:
        Regex replaceWithAt = new Regex("<%:*\\s*");
        // Match  %>, <% (but only if there's a proceeding })
        Regex replaceWithEmpty = new Regex("\\s*%>|<%\\s*(?=})");

        var replaceWithMvcHtmlStrings = replaceWithMvcHtmlString.Matches(view);
        foreach (Match mvcString in replaceWithMvcHtmlStrings) {
            view = view.Replace(mvcString.Value, "@MvcHtmlString.Create(" + mvcHtmlStringVariable.Match(mvcString.Value).Value + ")");
            }

        view = replaceWithEmpty.Replace(view, String.Empty);
        view = replaceWithAt.Replace(view, "@");

        Regex contentPlaceholderBegin = new Regex("<asp:Content[\\w\\W]*?>");
        Regex contentPlaceholderId = new Regex("(?<=ContentPlaceHolderID=\").*?(?=\")");
        Regex contentPlaceholderEnd = new Regex("</asp:Content>");
        MatchCollection contentPlaceholders = contentPlaceholderBegin.Matches(view);
        foreach (Match cp in contentPlaceholders) {
            view = view.Replace(cp.Value, "@section " + contentPlaceholderId.Match(cp.Value).Value + " {");
        }
        view = contentPlaceholderEnd.Replace(view, "}");

        // if we have something like @Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl");, replace it with @{ Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); }
        Regex render = new Regex("@Html\\.\\S*\\(.*\\)\\S*?;");
        var renderMatches = render.Matches(view);
        foreach (Match r in renderMatches) {
            view = view.Replace(r.Value, "@{ " + r.Value.Substring(1) + " }");
        }


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create)) {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(view);
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Users of ReSharper may like to vote for a feature to automatically convert from aspx to cshtml.  ReSharper will have an AST representation for both sides, so they could (in theory) do a very robust job of it without requiring regexs.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-194060